# Difference in Value between latest two rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as follows:

```
Id  |   Name    |   Value   |   RegisterDate
--------------------------------------------------
1   |   name1   |   11      |   2018-01-01
2   |   name2   |   12      |   2018-01-02
3   |   name3   |   13      |   2018-01-03
4   |   name4   |   14      |   2018-01-04
5   |   name5   |   15      |   2018-02-05
6   |   name6   |   16      |   2018-02-06
7   |   name7   |   17      |   2018-02-07
8   |   name8   |   18      |   2018-02-08
```

I want a query to get different value between two latest value fields `Order By Desc RegisterDate`?

In above sample query result is = `18 - 17 = 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way using `lag()` to access the previous value and `TOP` to only get the latest.

```
SELECT TOP(1)
       value - lag(value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY registerdate)
       FROM elbat
       ORDER BY registerdate DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there a bunch of ways to solve this, but here is one solution.

```
--Set up demo data
declare @T TABLE 
    (Id int, [Name] varchar(5), [Value] int, RegisterDate varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO @T
    (Id, [Name], [Value], RegisterDate)
VALUES
    (1, 'name1', 11, '2018-01-01'),
    (2, 'name2', 12, '2018-01-02'),
    (3, 'name3', 13, '2018-01-03'),
    (4, 'name4', 14, '2018-01-04'),
    (5, 'name5', 15, '2018-02-05'),
    (6, 'name6', 16, '2018-02-06'),
    (7, 'name7', 17, '2018-02-07'),
    (8, 'name8', 18, '2018-02-08')
;

--The query
--Using Row_Number and Order Desc
--We know that rn1 = last row and rn2 = 2nd to last row
WITH _cte
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY registerdate DESC
            ) AS rn
    FROM @T
    )
SELECT rn1.[value] - rn2.[value] AS result
FROM _cte rn1
JOIN _cte rn2 ON rn1.rn = 1
    AND rn2.rn = 2
```

---

```
| result |
|--------|
| 1      |
```